# Any other way to run cucumber scenario multiple times other than from scenario outline?

Tags: java, cucumber

Scenario outline :

- Given I have a stream from system-env
- When I request the streaming url
- Then A http response 200 received
- And I verify "data1" is accurate
- And I verify "data2" is accurate

Examples:

```
  |data1|data2|

  |abc|def|

  |test1|test2 |
```

What is the best way to make sure the above scenario is run for different input "stream" (currently received from system property to gradle task for a single stream as a tag and scenario is tagged with the same)?

I want to scale it to 50 streams or 100 streams later, I don't want to add all of those examples in examples as its too tedious.

I am thinking to collect all streams from an `yaml` file (suppose 50) and run the above scenario for each stream.

Comment: I would just create a simple feature where I can read the "stream" from file, database or yaml and generate this feature file on the fly so that I can test for all combinations without writing the scenario outline for each of them.

Comment: What do you mean "generate this feature file on the fly " ? currently i am reading all streams from yaml in the first step : Given i have a stream from System-env (if system-env) is not specified/null. so that it can work for if any stream is passed in. If not then it picks up streams from yaml file.

Comment: If you want to read directly from the yaml then you might have to provide a differentiate all those 50 streams, I believe that's going to be tedious. Just a thought, you make it as an yaml list and then convert to java array and loop through the steps...

Comment: thats exactly what i was trying to do, the only problem with that is, to dictate the scenario to run for each input ( i mean for all the steps in the scenario)

Comment: Can you share the step def for `When I request the streaming url` so that I can through the light on how to change that step.

Comment: "Given("^I have the stream from system-env$", () -> {
           String stream = System.getProperty("stream");
           List<String> streams = scenarioState.getConfigurations().getConfigStreamingAllChannels().getStreams();
           if (stream == null) {
               scenarioState.setStreams(streams);
           } else {
               scenarioState.getStreams().add(stream);
           }

       });"

Comment: I am heading to a meeting. will ping you once back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the high level approach that you can follow using the `Jackon` library to read the data from yaml and use it in the script. You can get the stream url based on the system variable `stream` which holds the index of the streams.

```
Given("^I have the stream from system-env$", () ->
{
    String myTargetStream ="";
    String[] streams = get_text_from_yaml_using_jackon_library_here;//you have to implement this
    int stream = System.getProperty("stream");
    if (stream+1>streams.length){
        myTargetStream = streams[0];
        System.setProperty("stream", "0");
    }else{
        myTargetStream = streams[stream+1];
        System.setProperty("stream", Integer.toString(stream+1));
    }
    // now use the myTargetStream in your test or generate the feature file here
});
```

Comment: "generate the feature file here" is the bit i cant get my head around it. so now we have myTargetStream , but how i dictate the cucumber to run the same scenario N number of times (depending on String[] streams size)  for the same examples data is what i am still confused with ? Would you be able to give me some light on that ?

Comment: Sure, let me update the answer. with the feature file generation logic.